# sqlite timecode calculations

Tags: sqlite, video-editing

I have two tables which I export from my video editing suite, one ("MediaPool") containing a row for each media file imported into the project, another ("Montage") for the portions of that file used in a specific edit. The fields that are associated between the two are MediaPool.FileName and Montage.Name, which are very similar (Filename only adds the file extension).

```
# MediaPool

Filename       | Take
---------------------------------
somefile.mp4   | Getty
file2.mov      | Associated Press
file3.mov      | Associated Press
```

and

```
# Montage

Name           | RecordIn    | RecordOut
------------------------------------------
somefile       | 01:01:01:01 | 01:01:20:19
somefile       | 01:05:15:23 | 01:05:16:10
somefile       | 01:25:19:10 | 01:30:16:04
file2          | 01:30:11:10 | 01:31:18:12
file2          | 01:40:15:22 | 01:42:21:17
```

The tables contain many more columns of course, but only the above is relevant.

Only the "MediaPool" table contains the field called "Take" which designates the file's copyright holder (long story). It can't be included in the "Montage" export. I needed to calculate the total duration of footage used from each source, by subtracting the RecordIn timecode from RecordOut and adding each result. This turned out to be more complicated than I expected, as I have some notions of programming but almost none when it comes to SQL (sqlite in my case).

I managed to come up with the following, which works fine and runs in under 4 seconds. However, from the little programming I've done, it seems overlong and very inelegant. Is there a shorter way to achieve this?

BTW, I'm using 25 fps timecode and I can't use LPAD in sqlite.

```
    SELECT 
        Source,
        SUBSTR('00' || CAST(DurationFrames/(60*60*25) AS TEXT), -2, 2) || ':' ||
        SUBSTR('00' || CAST(DurationFrames%(60*60*25)/(60*25) AS TEXT), -2, 2) || ':' ||
        SUBSTR('00' || CAST(DurationFrames%(60*60*25)%(60*25)/25 AS TEXT), -2, 2) || ':' || 
        SUBSTR('00' || CAST(DurationFrames%(60*60*25)%(60*25)%25 AS TEXT), -2, 2)
        AS DurationTC
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MediaPool.Take AS Source, 
        Montage.RecordIn, 
        Montage.RecordOut, 
        SUM(CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordOut, 1, 2) AS INT)*3600*25 + 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordOut, 4, 2) AS INT)*60*25  + 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordOut, 7, 2) AS INT)*25 + 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordOut, 10, 2) AS INT) - 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordIn, 1, 2) AS INT)*3600*25 - 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordIn, 4, 2) AS INT)*60*25 - 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordIn, 7, 2) AS INT)*25 - 
            CAST(SUBSTR(Montage.RecordIn, 10, 2) AS INT))
        AS DurationFrames
    FROM
        MediaPool
    JOIN 
        Montage ON MediaPool.FileName LIKE '%' || Montage.Name || '%'
    GROUP BY
        Take
    ORDER BY 
        Take
    )
```

Comment: What do the various fields in the timecode mean? Day, hour, minute, seconds?

Comment: If the Name is always the FIlename minus the extension, you can join on `MediaPool.Filename LIKE Montage.Name || '.%'` which should be faster than what you're doing, but ideally you should have an integer primary key for the MediaPool table that the rows in Montage refer to as a foreign key so you don't have to do string matching at all.

Comment: HH:MM:SS:FF (frames)

Comment: Ideally yes... But I'm limited by the CSV export function of my editing program, which is already ahead of what most editing programs like to export. Been doing this by hand for years... And yes, thank you. Removing the leading wildcard shaved off 30% running time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified query that produces the same results as yours on your test data. Mostly it uses `printf()` instead of a bunch of string concatenation and `substr()`s, and uses `strftime()` to calculate the total seconds of the hours minutes seconds part of the timecode:

```
WITH frames AS
 (SELECT Take, sum((strftime('%s', substr(RecordOut,1,8))*25 + substr(RecordOut,10))
                 - (strftime('%s', substr(RecordIn,1,8))*25 + substr(RecordIn,10)))
                  AS DurationFrames
  FROM MediaPool
  JOIN Montage ON MediaPool.Filename LIKE Montage.Name || '.%'
  GROUP BY Take)
SELECT Take AS Source
     , printf("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", DurationFrames/(60*60*25),
                                     DurationFrames%(60*60*25)/(60*25),
                                     DurationFrames%(60*60*25)%(60*25)/25,
                                     DurationFrames%(60*60*25)%(60*25)%25)
                                     AS DurationTC
FROM frames
ORDER BY Take;
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use printf and strftime in SQL. Nice trick with strftime there! Thanks a lot.